# Matlab 3D reconstruction

Tags: matlab, 3d, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

Recently, I have to do a project of multi view 3D scanning within this 2 weeks and I searched through all the books, journals and websites for 3D reconstruction including Mathworks examples and so on. I written a coding to track matched points between two images and reconstruct them into 3D plot. However, despite of using detectSURFFeatures() and extractFeatures() functions, still some of the object points are not tracked. How can I reconstruct them also in my 3D model?

Comment: May I know how to relate dense reconstruction with 3D multi view scanning with only 1 webcam? The website you posted is using stereo vision camera but what I do is using SfM as it can compute the 3D coordinates of object without restricting camera orientation.

Comment: If you want me to see your comment, please make it a comment to my answer, not to your question. :)  Take a look at this example: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/sparse-3-d-reconstruction-from-multiple-views.html

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is called "dense reconstruction". The best way to do this is with calibrated cameras.  Then you can rectify the images, compute disparity for every pixel (in theory), and then get 3D world coordinates for every pixel. Please check out this [Stereo Calibration and Scene Reconstruction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/stereo-vision.html) example.

Answer (score 1):

The tracking approach you are using is fine but will only get sparse correspondences.  The idea is that you would use the best of these to try to determine the difference in camera orientation between the two images.  You can then use the camera orientation to get better matches and ultimately to produce a dense match which you can use to produce a depth image.

Tracking every point in an image from frame to frame is *hard* (its called scene flow) and you won't achieve it by identifying individual features (such as SURF, ORB, Freak, SIFT etc.) because these features are by definition 'special' in that they can be clearly identified between images.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the Computer Vision Toolbox of Matlab you could use their matching functions. 
You can start for example by checking out this article about [disparity](http://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/disparity.html) and the related matlab functions.

In addition you can read about different matching techniques such as block matching, semi-global block matching and global optimization procedures. Just to name a few keywords. But be aware that the topic of stereo matching is huge one.